# Shouldn't the Manifest file be named "AndroidManifest" in the editor?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm getting a nonsensical error message:

> The element type "manifest" must be terminaed by the mathing end-tag `</manifest>`.

This is odd because that is not a problem in the manifest file. What IS odd, though, is that although the file is named `AndroidManifest.xml` in the Package Explorer, when I have it open in the editor its name there is `<ProjectName> Manifest`.

It should read "AndroidManifest" right?

If so, how can I get it to know that it is that, and not `<Project Name> Manifest`?

Comment: what is your project name? is it empty by any chance? The manifest file is by default opened in an Android Manifest Editor, which reads "*projectname* Manifest" in the name of the tab. Is your manifest tag closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <strike>It's strange that your editor would not show you the correct name of the file, but if you're sure you're opening the `AndroidManifest.xml` in your project's root directory, I don't see how it matters.</strike>
2. Since you haven't told us which editor you're using, how are we to say what's normal for that editor? If your editor is an IDE that knows about Android, maybe it's trying to be useful and indicate that this is your package's manifest. **Update:** Now that I've fixed the formatting of your question, we can see what you actually wrote, and it appears that this is the case. Your editor is telling you that you are editing the manifest for your project.
3. The error message that your `<manifest>` tag needs a matching end tag isn't nonsensical at all; it's very important.